# Wiremock: set unique identifier to mock using JSON

Tags: wiremock

I'm using Wiremock and during a test I want to edit a mock that was defined at startup in a JSON file inside /mappings directory (a default mock).

I know that I can define an UUID in the JSON file, but I'm looking for something that is human readable (it is probably not a good idea to mention a meaningless UUID inside a test). I saw that I can define a name, but how can I edit a mock using its name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [metadata](http://wiremock.org/docs/stub-metadata/) and WireMock's Admin API.

```js
...
"metadata": {
    "name": "My Mapping"
}
...
```

Then using the [find stub mappings by metadata](http://wiremock.org/docs/api/#tag/Stub-Mappings/paths/%7E1__admin%7E1mappings%7E1find-by-metadata/post), you can retrieve an array of matched objects.

```json
POST /__admin/mappings/find-by-metadata

{
    "matchesJsonPath" : {
      "expression" : "$.name",
      "contains" : "My Mapping"
    }
}
```

You can parse the response for a specific UUID, and finally [update a stub mapping by UUID](http://wiremock.org/docs/api/#tag/Stub-Mappings/paths/%7E1__admin%7E1mappings%7E1%7BstubMappingId%7D/put).

Alternatively, you could query the Admin API for all mappings and find the one that matches the one you want, but I find filtering by metadata a little easier to use.

Additionally, depending on your language of use for tests, you could make something like an enum that maps a human-readable name ("My Mapping") to a UUID, and skip the step where you have to find the stub by metadata/parse all mappings, instead just using that enum value to update the stub.

Comment: I don't like the complexity of this solution but I understand that is the only way using that tool, thanks!